# Generate type reference node with array access

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create this type reference:

```
Parameters<Foo['bar']>[0]
```

how do I achieve this using `ts.createTypeReferenceNode`?

```
ts.createTypeReferenceNode('Parameters', [
    ts.createTypeReferenceNode(`Foo['bar']`, []),
])
```

allows no array access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ts-ast-viewer.com](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAHgLhgBQIYCdUFsCmUfoQA8AYiCANoDkARhlQLoB8FADAwNxA), you'd need to use `ts.createIndexedAccessTypeNode` and `ts.createLiteralTypeNode`:

```js
        ts.createIndexedAccessTypeNode(
          ts.createTypeReferenceNode(
            ts.createIdentifier("Parameters"),
            [ts.createIndexedAccessTypeNode(
              ts.createTypeReferenceNode(
                ts.createIdentifier("Foo"),
                undefined
              ),
              ts.createLiteralTypeNode(ts.createStringLiteral("bar"))
            )]
          ),
          ts.createLiteralTypeNode(ts.createNumericLiteral("0"))
        )
```

Comment: Thank you! Using `ts.createIndexedAccessTypeNode` solved it for me. https://ts-ast-viewer.com/ is a great tip, previously I manually figured out how to generate the code.